# Open subsets of $S$ are the intersections of $S$ with open subsets of $X$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Let $X$ be an arbitrary metric space and $S$ be an arbitrary subset of $X$. Show that if $V$ is any open subset of $S$, then there exists an open subset $U$ of $X$ such that $V = U \cap S$.

If $V$ is an open subset of $S$ then it is a collection of open balls in $S$. Likewise, $U$ is a collection of open balls in $X$. Doesn't this just mean that $U$ completely encompasses $S$ and therefore the intersection of $U$ and $S$ is just $U$?

Comment: (i think your $W$ shd read $V$ btw) if $S \subset X$ then the topology on $X$ induces a topology on $S$ whose open sets are  exactly the intersections with $S$ of open subsets $U$ of $X$. this is a definition of the induced topology

Comment: I think yo are confused (if I understood your question) an open set in $S$ is not neccesarily open in $X$..

Answer (score 1):

This is the definition of subspace topology(metric).Here $S$ considered with 
subspace topology(metric) so $S$ may not be open in $X$ at all. This means that 
open sets of $S$ are whose are open in $X$ but does not have elements that are not 
presented in $S$.

Hope that I correctly understand your question and this be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

suppose $V$ is open relative to $S$ then for each $v\in V$ there is a real number $\delta$ such that if $s\in S$ and $d(s,v)<\delta$ then $s\in V$, then consider the set of all $x\in X$ such that $d(x,v)<\delta$ and consider the union of all those sets, then is easy to conclude..

Answer (score 0):

bearing in mind what you said about your professor's motivation, the nub of the question may be something like this:

we look at the open r-balls centred at $s_0 \in S$

(a) in X: $B_X(s_0,r) = \{x \in X | d(s_0,x) \lt r\}$

(b) in S: $B_S(s_0,r) = \{s \in S | d(s_0,s) \lt r\}$

now because $S \subset X$  we have

$$B_S(s_0,r) = S \cap B_X(s_0,r)$$

you can now show that same holds for any open set, since by definition it is a union of open balls and (for any index set):
$$
\cup_{\alpha} (S \cap B_{\alpha}) = S \cap (\cup_{\alpha} B_{\alpha})
$$

here the concreteness of definition of open sets provided by the metric topology is a clear guide to the motivation for defining the (induced) subset topology in the general case.